# Using MEF with generic base class

Tags: c#, generics, mef

I'm trying to figure how I can use MEF to import derived classes of a generic baseclass.
This is a general description of the classes:

```
interface IPlugin {}

abstract class PluginBase<T> : IPlugin {}

[Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
class Plugin1 : PluginBase<T1> {

    public Plugin1(T1 t1) : base(t1) {};

}

[Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
class Plugin2 : PluginBase<T2> {

    public Plugin1(T2 t2) : base(t2) {};
}

[ImportMany(typeof(IPlugin))]
List<IPlugin> importedList { get; set; }
```

I'm using the following code in order to load the plugins:

```
 var aggCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(catalogList);
 var container = new CompositionContainer(aggCatalog, 
            CompositionOptions.DisableSilentRejection);
 container.ComposeParts(this);
```

But I get an empty list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your types have non-default constructors so MEF cannot construct objects for you. Add `[ImportingConstructor]` attribute to constructors. And don't forget to add T1 and T2 objects into the `container`.

Comment: Wow, This was actually much simpler than I thought.. Should have posted SO hours ago :). I've tried the 'ImportingConstructor' attribute but missed adding T1,T2 to the container!.